# Change or override str from subclass method

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, inheritance, subclass

I had a problem with overriding str inside my inherited class. Is there a way to do something similar?

```
class Sentence(str):
        
    def input(self, msg):
        """Extend allow to hold one changing object for various strings."""
        self = Sentence(input(msg))

    def simplify(self):
        self = self.lower()
        self.strip()
```

I want to change mine string contained in that class, for various use. There's a way to do this? Because I tried many things from stack, and no one help me.

There is a explain what I want to do:

In init, I initialize Sentence class:

```
self.sentence = Sentence("")
```

Mainloop, where user can change Sentence:

```
self.sentence.input("Your input:")
```

After it I want to simplify string for alghoritm:

```
self.sentence.simplify()
```

And that's all, after it I want to use self.sentence like string.

---

But in both methods:

```
    def input(self, msg):
        """Extend allow to hold one changing object for various strings."""
        self = Sentence(input(msg))

    def simplify(self):
        self = self.lower()
        self.strip()
```

String wasn't changed.

Comment: This question could benefit from a more thorough explanation of what you're trying to do and what exactly your example is doing wrong.

Comment: Assigning to `self` in a method accomplishes nothing, all you've done is change a local variable that will disappear when the method returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the optimizations languages such as Python perform on strings (i.e. they are inmutable so the same string can be reused) I don't think it's a good practice to inherit from str, instead, you could write a class that wraps the string:

```
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, msg: str):
        self.msg = msg

    def simplify(self):
        self.msg = self.msg.lower().strip()
```

This way you can improve your implementation if for example you are changing the string too often and you run into performance problems.

Comment: Okay, i tryied to avoid that way, but if it is only one correct way, then it's my answer. Thank you :)